# how to convert a javascript callback to Objective-C using JavaScriptCore

Tags: javascript, ios

JS code:

```
share({
text:"test text",
url:"http://codingnext.com",
callback:function(){
    console.log('test func');
  }
});
```

Objective-C code:

```
- (void)share:(NSDictionary *)params {
    NSString *text = params[@"text"];
    NSString *url = params[@"url"];
    JSValue *callBack = params[@"callback"];
    [callBack callWithArguments:nil];
  }
```

I got the right text and url ,but the wrong callback.I want to know why and how to fix it .

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197587/how-can-i-pass-a-javascript-callback-function-to-cocoa-obj-c)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pass a JavaScript callback function to Cocoa/Obj-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197587/how-can-i-pass-a-javascript-callback-function-to-cocoa-obj-c)

Comment: Yes,but my problem is different.The params and callback are mixed so the Obj-C code can't figure out which should turn to JSValue. And when I use params[@"callback"],the application exits.